# How can I get a dbschema file of an existing sql 2005/2008 database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, db-schema

there are two databases to compare,but I can't connect one database directly.
so I want to compare the schema,then get a script to update one database.
VS2010 can compare two databases by **dbschema file**.
How can I get a dbschema file of an existing sql 2005/2008 database, Notes:the machine which has the database doesn't  install vs2010.

ty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [VSDBCMD.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) that allows you to generate .dbschema files.